# Bevel Modifier - Materials Issue

Tags: materials, shaders, bevel

I am trying to use a bevel modifier to help define the shape of a character's mouth. I want the inside of the mouth to use a separate color from the exterior of the face. I cannot figure out a way to use the bevel modifier in a way that does not make the inner mouth color extend to the face (creating the look of "lips"). When I use the "material index" option on the Bevel Modifier, it removes the color from the face exterior, but the interior mouth color is incorrect and patchy. Is there a way to fix this to get the desired result? Thank you!

[image]

[image: Desired result (Bevel Modifier is inactive]

[image: Incorrect result - patchy inner mouth using Bevel Modifier Material Offset]

[image: Incorrect result - material spreads to the exterior of face]

Comment: Hi, Wy ! If you cut the relevant chunk out of your model and shared on https://blend-exchange.com/ , then folks could check that their suggestions were working

Comment: Thanks Robin, the Blendfile is now added.

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing around to find a solution for you. When I tried to add segments to my bevel modifier it seemed to do the trick.

If not maybe playing with the material index?

[image]

[image]